# How check format of regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression and I want to check this regular expression is valid or not(correct format).

I try to use this code as below to check but it run not good

```
var regExp = new RegExp();
regExp.compile("^[\d\-]{0,64}"); => check OK.
regExp.compile("[[\d\-]{0,64}"); => check Not Good.
```

How to check my regular expression is correct format or not?
Please help me handle this case.

Comment: Need to escape the second `[` to match it literally

Comment: Are you asking for a way to check if your JavaScript _syntax_ be correct, or do you want a way to check if the regex be _logically_ correct (meaning it matches what you want to match) ?

Comment: Use try/catch around the regexp definition.

Comment: Seems slightly odd to mark a question as a duplicate of a question which was closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use try/catch to catch the error when creating the regexp.

```
Object.defineProperty(RegExp, 'compile', {
    value: function (regexp) {
        try {
            new RegExp(regexp);
            return "OK";
        } catch(e) {
            return "Not Good";
        }
    }
});
```

Some might object to adding methods to the `RegExp` object. In the above, I've adopted your proposed interface implementing this as `RegExp.compile`.

Comment: Quick Q: Why not defining property directly on RegExp proto? Any advantage of using `Object.def...`

Comment: `new RegExp("[[\d-]{0,64}")` return error ?

Comment: @guest271314 This will not return error. This will only check if the passed string can be complied to regex. And for your example, the regex is compiled to `/[[d-]{0,64}/` which is valid regex, but will not match what OP/you might expect.

Comment: @Tushar There is no way to check if a regexp does what the OP expects, because the computer has no way to know what he expects.